# Find if selected Checkboxes in repeater is of which gender

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, find, repeater

I have a repeater where I have a column with checkboxes and one column with gender which i populate with database value.

I want to find out if user has selected multiple checkboxes of same gender e.g. male if so do something otherwise If a user selects multiple checkboxes with a mixture of male and female then do something else.

so far I was thinking to add this to a list and then see if list has same values but not sure if it is best idea here is my code (I have a hidden field to get gender ), I am running this on click event of a button:

```
 foreach (RepeaterItem rptItem in myrepeater.Items)
        {
            hiddenGender = rptItem.FindControl("hiddenGender") as HiddenField;

            if (Convert.ToInt32(hiddenGender.Value) == 0)
            {
                gender.Add(0);
            }
            else if (Convert.ToInt32(hiddenGender.Value) == 1)
            {
                gender.Add(1);
            }
            else if (Convert.ToInt32(hiddenGender.Value) == 2)
            {
                gender.Add(2);
            }
        }
```

ps without usage of linq as it is framework 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it, here is the code to maybe help others(first I get the first item and see if it matches next item) :

```
public static bool ListEquality(IEnumerable<int> lstGender)
{
    int? first = null;
    bool isUnique = true;
    foreach (var item in lstGender)
    {
        if (first == null)
        {
            first = item;
        }
        else if (first.Value != item)
        {
            isUnique = false;
        }
    }
    return isUnique;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand what you want to do, but if i do, this code does the same:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem rptItem in myrepeater.Items)
{
     hiddenGender = rptItem.FindControl("hiddenGender") as HiddenField;
     gender.Add(Convert.ToInt32(hiddenGender.Value));
}
```

Comment: Basically I want to find out if my list contains same values....withoutusing linq